# Intermittent Hang in Python on openai.ChatCompletion.create() Method Call with GPT-3

Tags: python, python-3.x, freeze, openai-api, gpt-3

I am encountering a strange bug while using the openai Python library. Specifically, the method `openai.ChatCompletion.create()` intermittently hangs during execution without any error messages or exceptions being raised.

I am working on a script to process a dataset of 100 strings using a custom class named `GPTHandler`.

I'm running on windows 11, python 3.11.3, openai library v 0.28.1

The script reads strings from a spreadsheet, processes them, and sends them to the OpenAI GPT-3.5 Turbo model for text completion. Here's a simplified version of the setup:

```
import openai

class GPTHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        # Load base payload configuration from a config file
        # ...

    def use_gpt(self, string_to_be_processed):
        # Update the payload with the new string
        # ...
        payload = self._build_gpt_payload(string_to_be_processed)  
        # validated with logs this returns a valid payload on calls that hang
        # {
        #     "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        #     "mesages": [
        #         {
        #             "role": "user",
        #             "content": "This is a test string."
        #         }
        #     ]
        # }
        try:
            print("Sending API request...")
            gpt_response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(**payload)
            print("API request complete.")
            return gpt_response
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception: {e}")

# Load strings from spreadsheet
# ...

# Instantiate GPTHandler
gpt_handler = GPTHandler()

# Process each string
for string in strings:
    gpt_handler.use_gpt(string)
```

The issue occurs intermittently. The terminal prints "Sending API request..." but then hangs indefinitely without printing "API request complete." or raising any exception. Initially, I thought it was a delay, but even after waiting for 20 minutes, the hang persists. Notably, pressing `Ctrl+C` doesn’t terminate the script, and I have to kill the terminal to stop it. This hang happens on different strings and after a varying number of API calls.

I implemented a `TimeoutTracer` class to set a timeout using `sys.settrace`, hoping to interrupt the hang and gather more information.

```
class TimeoutTracer:
    def __init__(self, start, TOTAL_TIMEOUT):
        self.start = start
        self.TOTAL_TIMEOUT = TOTAL_TIMEOUT

    def trace_function(self, frame, event, arg):
        logger.debug(f"trace called at time: {time.time()}")
        if time.time() - self.start > self.TOTAL_TIMEOUT:
            logger.error(f"{'#'*20} ERROR {'#'*20}")
            logger.error(f"Timeout of {self.TOTAL_TIMEOUT} seconds exceeded!")
            raise Exception('Timed out!')
        return self.trace_function



class GPTHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        # ...

    def use_gpt(self, string_to_be_processed):
        payload = self._build_gpt_payload(string_to_be_processed)
        TOTAL_TIMEOUT = 60
        start = time.time()
        tracer = TimeoutTracer(start, TOTAL_TIMEOUT)
        sys.settrace(tracer.trace_function)
        try:
            print("Sending API request...")
            gpt_response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(**payload)
            print("API request complete.")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error: {e}")
            return "{}"
        finally:
            sys.settrace(None)  # Remove the time constraint and continue normally.
        # ... (process gpt_response)

# ... (rest of the script including loading strings and processing loop)
```

I had a log output for every time `sys.settrace` was called and found that when it hangs, `sys.settrace` stops being called, which suggests that no code is being executed during these hang periods. This might also explain why `Ctrl+C` isn’t working. Additionally, I am not hitting any rate limits as OpenAI would return a message in that case.

I am looking for insights or suggestions on what could be causing this hang and how to resolve or debug it further. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have the exact same pb , with gpt4-32k since yesterday. It seems related to prompt length in my case , i'm well below the 32k limit in every call, but somehow, for longer exemple the call freeze (no error, no response...). Did you find a solution ?